# Как сгенерировать приватный ключ ETH?

Tags: c#, ethereum

Приватный ключ Эфира это просто набор определенных символов длинной 64 символа или есть какая то закономерность? Есть да , то как создать приватный ключ на c#?

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: @aepot Да, спасибо. Ставил лайк, но в данный момент система не разрешает

Comment: @aepot Готово. Еще раз спасибо:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот ключ - всего-лишь последовательность из 32 случайных байт, записанных в шестнадцатеричном виде.

```cs
Random rnd = new Random();
string key = string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 32)
    .Select(_ => rnd.Next(0, 256).ToString("x2")));
Console.WriteLine(key);
```

```
a54caa9fe9057d4a42a75bd75ed1d5c44597c76d8b630324b4e38d821583511e
```

Ну или для параноиков есть такой вариант

```cs
byte[] bytes = new byte[32];
using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rnd = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    rnd.GetBytes(bytes);
string key = string.Concat(bytes.Select(x => x.ToString("x2")));
Console.WriteLine(key);
```

```cs
a8bb1c78402d7050f88c14ed4d923820d8c5aa531205ef3a0f7b5e9784298e44
```

Если уж совсем по канонам пойти, то есть [такой пример](http://mytenpennies.wikidot.com/blog:using-bouncy-castle).

> [Here](http://mytenpennies.wikidot.com/local--files/blog:using-bouncy-castle/Program.cs) is the complete source file.

Answer (score 0):

Генерация ключа Ethereum основана на эллиптической кривой ecp256k1. По сути приватный ключ это случайное число записанное в 16ричном виде.