# Как использовать secp256k1lib и keccak256 для создания криптокошелька?

Tags: c#, криптография, ethereum

Предположим, что у меня есть приватный ключ от ETH
Каким образом создается публичный ключ и адрес?

на гитхабе куча исходников, но судя по колличеству cs файлов там очень много лишнего.

Необходимо

Создаем приватный ключ -> из него с помощью secp256k1lib создаем публичный ключ -> потом из публичного создем адрес.

Все эти 3 ключа необходимо вывести на экран.

Как это сделать? Буду вечно благодарен, если у кого-нибудь завалялся исходник.

ПыСы: прошу какашками не кидаться, если бы разобрался сам не писал бы сюда.

Comment: [Оно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1276626/373567)

Comment: `но судя по колличеству cs файлов там очень много лишнего` - типично неверное суждение новичка. Чтобы понять, сколько там лишнего - нужно читать код, а не файлы считать.

Comment: @aepot Как вариант для приватного ключа пойдет. С этим то без проблем разобрался. Проблема заключается в публичном ключе и адресе. Скачивал эксемплы и через отладку с брекпоинтами смотрел, так и не понял. Документацию тоже читал. В гугле выдает только общую информацию а ля "сделай так, потом переведи в secp256k1lib , потом в кесак и будет счастье", но такой вариант далеко не подходит.

Comment: В том ответе в самом низу ссылка на другое решение.

Comment: Посмотрите как [реализовано в NEthereum](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum/blob/be4703a748722fe4e4ab7e37823f33c74d7044d6/src/Nethereum.Signer/EthECKey.cs#L191)